# WEBRTC - Socket node.js

Tags: node.js, socket, webrtc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando o seguinte sistema de socket (Usando FireBase) para comunicação:

```
openSocket: function(config) {
                var channel = config.channel || location.href.replace( /\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g , '');
                var socket = new Firebase('https://webrtc.firebaseIO.com/' + channel);

                socket.channel = channel;
                socket.on("child_added", function(data) {
                    config.onmessage && config.onmessage(data.val());
                });
                socket.send = function(data) {
                    this.push(data);
                };
                config.onopen && setTimeout(config.onopen, 1);
                socket.onDisconnect().remove();
                return socket;
            }
```

Quando tento criar um servidor de sinalização local usando:

```
openSocket: function (config) {
                var channelName = location.href.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g, ''); // using URL as room-name

                var SIGNALING_SERVER = 'http://localhost:12034/';
                connection.openSignalingChannel = function(config) {
                    config.channel = config.channel || this.channel;
                    var websocket = new WebSocket(SIGNALING_SERVER);
                    websocket.channel = config.channel;
                    websocket.onopen = function() {
                        websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                            open: true,
                            channel: config.channel
                        }));
                        if (config.callback)
                            config.callback(websocket);
                    };
                    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
                        config.onmessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
                    };
                    websocket.push = websocket.send;
                    websocket.send = function(data) {
                        websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                            data: data,
                            channel: config.channel
                        }));
                    };
                }
            }
```

A aplicação simplesmente deixa de responder. Nem mesmo gera algum erro no console. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro está nestas linhas:

```
websocket.push = websocket.send;
websocket.send = function(data) {
    websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
        data: data,
        channel: config.channel
    }));
};
```

Na primeira linha você está falando que **push** será **send**, na segunda você define **send**, só que a primeira coisa que você faz em **send** é chamar **push**, ao fazer isso você está criando uma exceção de estouro de pilha (stack overflow exception), já que você criou uma situação de recursão infinita. Ao entrar no método send, chama-se o método push, só que o método push é o método send, entende ?